# zip4j ZipFile getInputStream always returns byte array with size 1

Tags: java, zip4j

The following code always results to a byte array with size 1, any ideas ?

```
FileHeader fh = (FileHeader) packageFile.getFileHeaders().get(1);
InputStream inputStream = packageFile.getInputStream(fh);
byte[] bytes=new byte[inputStream.available()];
```

the zip file is fine!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you expect? Perhaps your understanding of `available()` isn't correct. The method returns an *estimate* but is dependent on implementation.

From the docs;

> Note that while some implementations of InputStream will return the
>   total number of bytes in the stream, many will not. It is never
>   correct to use the return value of this method to allocate a buffer
>   intended to hold all data in this stream.

It looks like you are defining a buffer `bytes` to read the data into.